# How can I get an Interbase password if I have only the BDE alias?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, interbase, bde

I am trying to connect to a Interbase DB at runtime via the BDE. I am trying to do this in a formless project (but not a console app). The alias is known. I retrieve the alias from the registry.  Example:  MyAlias.

```
//create alias params list  
AParams:= TStringList.Create;  

//create a session to get alias parameters  
ASession:= TSession.Create(nil);  
ASession.SessionName := 'MainSession';  
try  
 ASession.GetAliasParams(tmpAlias, AParams);  
finally  
 ASession.Free;  
end;  


//connect to database 
dbMain:= TDatabase.Create(nil);  
with dbMain do  
begin  
 //AliasName:= 'MyAlias';  
 DatabaseName:= 'test';  
 LoginPrompt:= False;  
 Params.Assign(AParams);  
 try  
  Connected:=True;  
  if Connected then ShowMessage('Connected!') else ShowMessage('Failed to Connect!');    
 finally  
  Free;  
 end; //try  
end;//with  

//free alias params list  
AParams.Free;
```

Anyway, it doesn't look like the Session.GetParams actually gets the password. How do I get the password? Is there a way to get all the connection info from the BDE and make the connection if I know the alias?  I'd rather not hard-code the username and password in case the client changes them in the future.

Comment: If I were your customer, I don't want that you can access my databases when you want, even I change the password. So, you should not even try to access a customer's data without his permission. And as RRUZ said information concerning the username,password,etc are stored into an encrypted file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shane, if you could get the password from the database only knowing the alias, all the security of the database will be pointless. **so the answer is NO** , you cannot retrieve this info only knowing the BDE alias. the way to connect to a database with a password protection is request the user and password to the final user or storing this info in an encrypted configuration file.

Comment: Thanks, i figured that much. I was just checking to be sure. I am going to use a encrypted file which stores the alias;username;password. If client changes their credentials in the future, then this encrypted file can be changed as well. - THANKS!